# Confused line of code

Tags: python

I am trying to understand a code I am not sure if I am right:

```
left_lines = [[310, 319, 318, 406, 317, 322],[423, 425, 425, 357, 419, 414]]
test = sorted([line[1] for line in left_lines])[int(len(left_lines)/2)]
```

How is this giving me only one number? Is it trying to find the smallest number in `left_lines[1]`?

**Update**

Reference: http://sdc.autojazari.com/lane-detection/

**Update 2**

I am new to Python

Comment: Why don't you ask the author?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What should be the expected output of this code?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't know who the author is

Comment: Looks like it's the median value out of all the second elements.

Comment: No, because the smallest number would be `319`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it apart.

```
In [3]: [line[1] for line in left_lines]
Out[3]: [319, 425]
```

gives you the second number from each sublist (you call a sublist a line)

```
sorted([line[1] for line in left_lines])
Out[4]: [319, 425]
```

sorts the received list.

Now the `[int(len(left_lines)/2)]` part puts an index to the received list. The index is the number of lines divided by 2 (and converted to an int).

So what this code does is, provided you have `x` lines is ordering the second number from each line from smallest to larges, and giving the middle value.

Perhaps this is a median of all the second items of all lines.

Comment: Yep True, my bad! Very new to Python

Answer (score 1):

```
left_lines = [[310, 319, 318, 406, 317, 322],[423, 425, 425, 357, 419, 414]]
test = sorted([line[1] for line in left_lines])[int(len(left_lines)/2)]
```

## left_lines

This code is a list of list meaning you have nested list declared.

## test

`sorted()` is a function for sorting purpose.

`[line[1]]` will return list of `[310, 319, 318, 406, 317, 322],[423, 425, 425, 357, 419, 414]`

`for line in left_lines` this will iterate throughout whole list in a sequential manner

`[int(len(left_lines)/2)] int(len())` to convert list length to int

`(left_lines)/2` will divide the lenght by 2

Answer (score 0):

```
[line[1] for line in left_lines]
```

this is known as list compression.

The output of above line will be second element (index 1) of each sublist of list left_lines [319,425].

Now sorted is built in function which returns sorted list (you can also sort tuples using this method).

```
sorted([line[1] for line in left_lines])=[319,425]
```

`len` is a built in function used to find the length of string, tuples or list. So

```
int(len(left_lines)/2)=1
```

Finally,

```
sorted([line[1] for line in left_lines])[int(len(left_lines)/2)]=[319,425][1]
```

which means the second element of the list i.e 425.

So test is equal to 425.